com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: isFocusable
Process: com.topurayhan.chatter, PID: 7960
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.topurayhan.chatter/com.topurayhan.chatter.CategoriesActivity}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: isFocusable
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: isFocusable
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(CustomClassMapper.java:478)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(CustomClassMapper.java:330)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(CustomClassMapper.java:61)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(DatabaseReference.java:282)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(DatabaseReference.java:159)
         at com.topurayhan.chatter.CategoriesActivity.onCreate(CategoriesActivity.java:236)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

I have this in my logcat, after trying to save the task onto the user's account with this code
package com.topurayhan.chatter;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import static com.topurayhan.chatter.R.drawable.avatar;
import static com.topurayhan.chatter.R.drawable.circle1;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms. tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.topurayhan.chatter.Hobbies.Hobbies_Categories;
import com.topurayhan.chatter.Home.Home_Categories;
import com.topurayhan.chatter.Lifestyle.Lifestyle_Categories;
import com.topurayhan.chatter.Schools.School_Categories;
import com.topurayhan.chatter.databinding.ActivityCategoriesBinding;
import com.topurayhan.chatter.databinding.ActivitySettingsBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class CategoriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityCategoriesBinding binding;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    CircleImageView avatar;
    TextView username, emailDisplay;
    String userId;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    List<DataClass_Task> dataList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    ValueEventListener eventListener;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    LinearLayout settings, watch, mail, calendar;
    List<DataClass_Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    ArrayList<User> users;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityCategoriesBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        settings = findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);
        watch = findViewById(R.id.watchActivity);
        mail = findViewById(R.id.chatsButton);
        calendar = findViewById(R.id.calendarActivity);
        ImageButton addTaskBtn = findViewById(R.id.addTaskBtn);

        addTaskBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CategoriesActivity.this, Task.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        watch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CategoriesActivity.this, Watch.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class));
            }
        });

        mail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
            }
        });

        calendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Calendar.class));
            }
        });

        CardView schoolCategories = findViewById(R.id.schoolCategories);
        CardView homeCategories = findViewById(R.id.homeCategories);
        CardView lifestyleCategories = findViewById(R.id.lifestyleCategories);
        CardView hobbiesCategories = findViewById(R.id.hobbiesCategories);

        schoolCategories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), School_Categories.class));
            }
        });

        homeCategories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home_Categories.class));
            }
        });

        lifestyleCategories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Lifestyle_Categories.class));
            }
        });

        hobbiesCategories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Hobbies_Categories.class));
            }
        });

        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        avatar = findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        emailDisplay = findViewById(R.id.emailDisplay);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.search);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser();

        userId = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        searchView.clearFocus();

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(CategoriesActivity.this,1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CategoriesActivity.this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setView(R.layout.progress_layout);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        dataList = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), dataList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tasks");
        dialog.show();

        eventListener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                dataList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot itemSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    DataClass_Task dataClassTask = itemSnapshot.getValue(DataClass_Task.class);
                    dataClassTask.setKey(itemSnapshot.getKey());
                    dataList.add(dataClassTask);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        DatabaseReference tasksRef = database.getReference("Tasks");

        // Generate a unique task ID
        String taskId = tasksRef.child("Tasks").push().getKey();




        // Now add the task under the "Tasks" node
        String tskId = database.getReference().child("users").child(auth.getUid()).child("Tasks").push().getKey();
        DataClass_Task task = new DataClass_Task();
        task.setTaskId(taskId);
        task.setKey("key");
        task.setDataTitle("Task Name");
        task.setDataDesc("Task Description");
        task.setDataDue("Task Due");




        database.getReference().child("users").child(auth.getUid()).child("Tasks").child(taskId).setValue(recyclerView)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        // Task saved successfully
                        Log.d(TAG, "Task saved successfully!");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // Failed to save task
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to save task: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });



        database.getReference().child("users").child(auth.getUid()).child("profileImage").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    String profileImage = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    Picasso.get().load(profileImage).into(binding.profileImage);
                    //binding.profilePic.setImageURI(Uri.parse(profileImage));
                }
                else {
                    @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables") Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(circle1);
                    binding.profileImage.setImageDrawable(d);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                searchList(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });

        avatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserInfo.class));
            }
        });
    }

    public void searchList(String text) {
        ArrayList<DataClass_Task> searchList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataClass_Task dataClassTask: dataList) {
            if(dataClassTask.getDataTitle().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                searchList.add(dataClassTask);
            }
        }
        adapter.searchDataList(searchList);
    }
}


I was expecting the code to work but it shows the error that I have provided in the logcat. But these are the code for the getters.

package com.topurayhan.chatter;

import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;

public class DataClass_Task {

    public String dataTitle;
    public String dataDesc;
    public String dataDue;


    public void setDataTitle(String dataTitle) {
        this.dataTitle = dataTitle;
    }

    public void setDataDesc(String dataDesc) {
        this.dataDesc = dataDesc;
    }

    public void setDataDue(String dataDue) {
        this.dataDue = dataDue;
    }

    public void setTaskId(String taskId) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
    }

    public DataClass_Task(String taskId) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getTaskId() {
        return taskId;
    }

    public String taskId;

    @Exclude
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String key;

    @Exclude
    public String getDataTitle() {
        return dataTitle;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getDataDesc() {
        return dataDesc;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getDataDue() {
        return dataDue;
    }

    public DataClass_Task(String dataTitle, String dataDesc, String dataDue) {
        this.dataTitle = dataTitle;
        this.dataDesc = dataDesc;
        this.dataDue = dataDue;
    }

    public void task(String dataTitle, String dataDesc, String dataDue, String taskId, String key) {
        this.dataTitle = dataTitle;
        this.dataDesc = dataDesc;
        this.dataDue = dataDue;
        this.taskId = taskId;
        this.key = key;
    }

    public DataClass_Task() {}

}


What should I do? Please help.
I want to get the task's data and align it with the user's account so each user has a customized tasks within their accounts.


If you encounter problems, it's best to create a MCVE when posting a question. You posted mare than 400 (four hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read how to ask a question.

Besides that, please edit your question and the class that contains the isFocusable field.
